# How to deploy my website online

Tags: codeigniter, web, web-hosting

I have a website build using Codeigniter Framework. I already uploaded it in a web server, TurnKey Lamp in Linux using Git Bash.. I can access it already since it is networked.. What I want now is to make it visible on internet.. How can I do that?

Comment: have you any domain?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam, I don't have..

Comment: then buy a domain and change your nameserver from domain control panel. `name server` will provided by your hosting provider